# ANTLR Lexer rule only seems to work as part of parser rule, and not part of another lexer rule

Tags: antlr, antlr4

If I have the following the grammar to parse a list of Integers separated by whitespace:

```
grammar TEST;

test
    : expression* EOF
    ;

expression
    : integerLiteral
    ;

integerLiteral
    : INTLITERAL
    ;

PLUS: '+';
MINUS: '-';

DIGIT: '0'..'9';
DIGITS: DIGIT+;
INTLITERAL: (PLUS|MINUS)? DIGITS;

WS: [ \t\r\n] -> skip;
```

It does not work! If I pass "100" I get:

```
line 1:0 extraneous input '100' expecting {<EOF>, INTLITERAL}
```

However if remove the lexer INTLITERAL rule and place it just under the parser rule integerLiteral like this

```
integerLiteral
    : (PLUS|MINUS)? DIGITS
    ;
```

Now it seems to work just fine!

I feel that if I am able to understand why this is I'll begin to understand some idiosyncrasies that I am experiencing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lexer creates tokens in the following manner:

1. try to match as many characters for a single token as possible
2. if two tokens match the same characters, let the one defined first "win"

Given the information from the 2 rules above, then you will see that your rules:

```
DIGITS: DIGIT+;
INTLITERAL: (PLUS|MINUS)? DIGITS;
```

are the problem. For the input `100` a `DIGITS` token is created: rule 2 applies here: both rules match `100`, but since `DIGITS` is defined before `INTLITERAL`, a `DIGITS` token is created.

### Solution 1

Move `INTLITERAL` above `DIGITS`:

```
INTLITERAL: (PLUS|MINUS)? DIGITS;
DIGIT: '0'..'9';
DIGITS: DIGIT+;
```

But now notice that `DIGIT` and `DIGITS` will never become tokens on their own because `INTLITERAL` will always be matched first. In this case, you can make both of these rules `fragment`s, and then it doesn't matter where you place them because `fragment` rules are only used inside other lexer rules (not in parser rules)

### Solution 2

Make `DIGIT` and `DIGITS` fragments

```
fragment DIGIT: '0'..'9';
fragment DIGITS: DIGIT+;
INTLITERAL: (PLUS|MINUS)? DIGITS;
```

### Solution 3

Or better, don't glue the operator on the `INTLITERAL` but match it in an unary expression:

```
expression
    : (MINUS | PLUS) expression
    | expression (MINUS | PLUS) expression
    | integerLiteral
    ;

integerLiteral
    : INTLITERAL
    ;

PLUS: '+';
MINUS: '-';

fragment DIGIT: '0'..'9';

INTLITERAL: DIGIT+;
```

Comment: ah ... thanks for the answer.  I had not run across as clear as an explanation as you provided!

Comment: Yeah, there are a lot of `extraneous input ... expecting` questions here on SO, but I never feel comfortable closing questions as duplicate since the solution always involves some grammar specific hints. You're welcome @jross.