# Antlr4: Skip line when it start with * unless the second char is

Tags: antlr4, language-design

In my input, a line start with `*` is a comment line unless it starts with `*+` or `*-`. I can ignore the comments but need to get the others.

This is my lexer rules:

```
WhiteSpaces : [ \t]+;
Newlines    : [\r\n]+;
Commnent    : '*' .*? Newlines -> skip ;
SkipTokens  : (WhiteSpaces | Newlines) -> skip;
```

An example:

```
* this is a comment line
** another comment line
*+ type value
```

So, the first two are comment lines, and I can skip it. But I don't know to to define lexer/parser rule that can catch the last line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `SkipTokens` lexer rule will never be matched because the rules `WhiteSpaces` and `Newlines` are placed before it. See this Q&A for an explanation how the lexer matches tokens: [ANTLR Lexer rule only seems to work as part of parser rule, and not part of another lexer rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62049674/antlr-lexer-rule-only-seems-to-work-as-part-of-parser-rule-and-not-part-of-anot)

For it to work as you expect, do this:

```
SkipTokens  : (WhiteSpaces | Newlines) -> skip;

fragment WhiteSpaces : [ \t]+;
fragment Newlines    : [\r\n]+;
```

What a `fragment` is, check this Q&A: [What does "fragment" mean in ANTLR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6487593/what-does-fragment-mean-in-antlr)

Now, for your question. You defined a `Comment` rule to always end with a line break. This means that there can't be a comment at the end of your input. So you should let a comment either end with a line break or the EOF.

Something like this should do the trick:

```
COMMENT
 : '*' ~[+\-\r\n] ~[\r\n]* // a '*' must be followed by something other than '+', '-' or a line break
 | '*' ( [\r\n]+ | EOF )   // a '*' is a valid comment if directly followed by a line break, or the EOF
 ;

STAR_MINUS
 : '*-'
 ;

STAR_PLUS
 : '*+'
 ;

SPACES
 : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip
 ;
```

This, of course, does not mandate the `*` to be at the start of the line. If you want that, checkout this Q&A: [Handle strings starting with whitespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66616831/handle-strings-starting-with-whitespaces/66623755#66623755)